SQL Server Configuration Manager doesn't show the IP
When I try to connect Java to SQL Server, I get the error:

Error: "connect timed out. Verify the connection properties. Make sure
that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting
TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the
port are not blocked by a firewall.".

After, I looked at some instructions to fix the error and there was a request to enter the IP in SQL Server Configuration Manager. But my computer only shows the protocol.
enter image description here

You certainly don't enter an IP in SSCM - that's assigned to the server itself in normal network manner
